# sql: - replace and unpivot functions in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, unpivot

Fiddle Example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/419ec/3

SQL server 2008.

I was wondering whether someone can please explain to me what is going on in the select query below with the replace function and unpivot function. I'm a newbie to sql and I don't understand the logic of that type of query (de-normalizing a table).

```
CREATE TABLE TableB
    ([date] datetime, [Id] int, [name] varchar(3), [blah1] varchar(4), [hour1] int, [hour2] int, [hour3] int, [hour4] int)
;

INSERT INTO TableB
    ([date], [Id], [name], [blah1], [hour1], [hour2], [hour3], [hour4])
VALUES
    ('2013-04-01 00:00:00', 1, 'Jim', 'test', 129, 343, 54, 89),
    ('2013-04-01 00:00:00', 2, 'Bob', 'rewe', 45, 6, 45, 2),
    ('2013-04-02 00:00:00', 3, 'Joe', 'fdf', 7, 8, 4, 3)
```

Select Query:

```
select date, 
  id, 
  name,
  replace(MightMouse, 'hour', '') hour,
  observationvalue
from tableB
unpivot
(
  observationvalue
  for MightMouse in (hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4)
) unpiv
```

I thought the usage of the replace function was as follows:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )

string_expression
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

As per the definition of the `replace` function, string_expression is the string in which a sub-string is being searched (the sub-string can be the full string). For example,

```
replace('mynameisjohn', 'john', '')
```

This would search for the sub-string `john` in string_expression `mynameisjohn` and replace it with empty string, resulting in a string that equals `mynameis`.

But in the above example, I don't understand what `MightyMouse` is. There is no `MightyMouse` in the original table. I also don't know how the unpivot part fits into the query as in the flow of execution.

If this was python for example there is a flow to the logic of the code that is intuitive. With SQL, it seems you can build ugly queries and from sql's perspective things work just fine. But from the user's perspective it can be difficult to decompose what is going on in different parts of the query code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` is a table operator, it operates on the table preceeding it:

```
tableName UNPIVOT (<unpivot-expression>)
```

Your `UNPIVOT` adds *two* extra columns (not one as has been implied), first the `observationvalue` column, which contains the values from the columns `(hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4)` rotated from horizontal to vertical.

And secondly it adds the `MightMouse` column which is the *Names* of the `(hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4)` columns that the corresponding current `observationvalue` was pulled from.

So this row:

```
hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4
129,   343,   54,    89
```

becomes these rows:

```
observationvalue MightMouse
129              hour1
343              hour2
 54              hour3
 89              hour4
```

(With the other corresponding column values also, of course)

Hopefully, this also makes clear what the REPLACE is doing and why it works.

---

As for the *effective*(*) order of execution: the `FROM` clause is always executed *first* in a SQL Query, then the `WHERE` clause.  The `SELECT` clause (the column list and column expressions) is almost last, and an `ORDER BY` clause would normally be last (there are some MS specific exceptions).

(* - this is only the "effective"/"logical" order of execution.  The SQL engine is allowed to do things in any actual order that it wants, so long as it has the same logical effect as this order)

Comment: Thank you RBarry for the detailed explanation. So I guess the `MightMouse` column name gets renamed `hour` as per the `replace(MightMouse, 'hour', '') hour` statement - is that correct?

Comment: Well, `MightMouse` has a column name of "MightMouse".  What gets replaced are the *contents* of the MightMouse column, which were constructed from the source column names (`hour1, hour2, ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot uses nested left outer join for each column specified in your case

```
 (hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4)
```

these column names are also part of the result  which is referred as MightMouse in your case

```
select replace('hour1','hour','')
select replace('hour2','hour','')
select replace('hour3','hour','')
```

in other words the same query can be written like this

```
select a.date,a.id, 
  a.name,replace('hour1', 'hour', '') as hour ,a.hour1 as observationvalue
from TableB a
left outer join TableB b
on a.hour1=b.hour1
where a.hour1 is not null
union

select a.date,a.id, 
  a.name,replace('hour2', 'hour', '') as hour ,a.hour2 as observationvalue
from TableB a
left outer join TableB b
on a.hour2=b.hour2
where a.hour2 is not null
union
select a.date,a.id, 
  a.name,replace('hou3', 'hour', '') as hour ,a.hour3 as observationvalue
from TableB a
left outer join TableB b
on a.hour3=b.hour3
where a.hour3 is not null
union
select a.date,a.id, 
  a.name,replace('hour4', 'hour', '') as hour ,a.hour4 as observationvalue
from TableB a
left outer join TableB b
on a.hour4=b.hour4
where a.hour4 is not null
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I appreciate it. But is the `left outer join TableB b on a.hour1=b.hour1 where a.hour1 is not null` part necessary? I executed the same code without that part for each of the hours and it produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

"MightMouse" is the name of the new column.  Essentially, you are taking all of those hour columns and smushing them into one column.  The "for MightMouse in ..." is calling the column MightMouse.  So then, you are replacing the literal string "hour" from that new column with an empty string.

Comment: Dave thanks for the comment. So I create a new column `MightMouse` that doesn't appear in the final query output but its there for processing the query? Then it smushes all of the hour columns into one that is named `hour`. I still don't understand the flow of the query. What part gets executed first? Does the unpivot get executed first?